# mod_rewrite external links issue (wordpress)

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, external

i have a redirect.php and a link and it doesn't work in WORDPRESS.

i expect when i click the "hello" link on my site, it goes to redirect.php, the user sees the spinner for 5 secs, and the users exits my site to hello.com

it looks like there is something wrong with mod_rewrite i'm unable to solve

i'd really appreciate a very detailed answers. i am very junior

this what i have.

1.- I have an external link in my homepage:

```
<a href="http://redirect.php?link=hello.com">Hello</a>
```

2.- In redirect.php, i have:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>" />
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <h1>You are leaving my site!</h1>
    <img src="/images/spinner.gif" alt="spinner" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link `<a href="http://redirect.php?...` is incorrect. This should most likely be `<a href="/redirect.php?...` or any subdirectory on your server.

You should also include the protocol in your link parameter or prepend it in your meta tag. Also make sure to HTML encode the link in your meta tag and to properly URL encode the domain name in your link parameter.

So, change the link to:

```
<a href="/redirect.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com">Hello</a>
```

if you have the redirect.php file in the root of your website. And change the meta tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['link'], ENT_QUOTES,);?>" />
```

And you might want to do some validation on the validity of the link parameter and you possibly also want to check the referrer URL (`$_SERVER('HTTP_REFERER')`) to make sure you only perform redirects for links from your own website (i.e. don't create an [open redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) vulnerability).